# why bootstrap offset is not working to both side?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page where In **first row** I want a space to the left side and in **second row** i want a space to the right side.

This space should be **col-md-2**

This space should be same to both **row** and this space **is not visible** after col-md-* **to** col-xs-*

So that I'm using following bootstrap code but not working :  It's showing space to left side on both row :(

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-11 text-message">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur bibendum ornare dolor, quis ullamcorper ligula sodales.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-1">
            <img src="<?php echo SITE_URL.'images/users_avator/ppic_5795beb6936d63.04385327.jpg' ?>" alt="User Avatar" class="img-responsive img-circle" width="50"/>
        </div>
    </div>

     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-1">
            <img src="<?php echo SITE_URL.'images/users_avator/ppic_5795beb6936d63.04385327.jpg' ?>" alt="User Avatar" class="img-responsive img-circle" width="50"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-11 text-message">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur bibendum ornare dolor, quis ullamcorper ligula sodales.</p>
        </div>            
    </div>  

</div>
```

**Update :**

Now I am using this code and it's showing space on col-sm-* grid like the bellow image. Space on second row between image and text.

```
   <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-11 text-message">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur bibendum ornare dolor, quis ullamcorper ligula sodales.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-1">
                <img src="<?php echo SITE_URL.'images/users_avator/ppic_5795beb6936d63.04385327.jpg' ?>" alt="User Avatar" class="img-responsive img-circle" width="50"/>
            </div>
        </div>

         <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-1">
                <img src="<?php echo SITE_URL.'images/users_avator/ppic_5795beb6936d63.04385327.jpg' ?>" alt="User Avatar" class="img-responsive img-circle" width="50"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-11 text-message">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur bibendum ornare dolor, quis ullamcorper ligula sodales.</p>
            </div>            
        </div>  

    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: In the second row just give `<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10">` instead of `<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">`, the left over space will be your required space

Comment: I used that but when the layout on col-sm-* grid then ti's showing me space between image and text in second row..

Comment: Update your code , give us more info on your problem , or create fiddle , that will help us in giving solution

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: seen. if a small class is not available then xs class will be imposed in grid , why not use ` col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10` for small resolution

Comment: after using col-sm-10 it's still showing me the space

Comment: it works for me , see I have updated code in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap offset will increase the left margin of a column by * columns

try to change this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10">
```

in place of this:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
```

the left over space will be your required space on right side

[info](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)

Updated code:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2  col-sm-10">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-11 text-message">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur bibendum ornare dolor, quis ullamcorper ligula sodales.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-1">
            <img src="<?php echo 'http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.gif' ?>" alt="User Avatar" class="img-responsive img-circle" width="50"/>
        </div>
    </div>

     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-md-10 col-sm-10">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-1">
            <img src="<?php echo 'http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.gif' ?>" alt="User Avatar" class="img-responsive img-circle" width="50"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-11 text-message">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur bibendum ornare dolor, quis ullamcorper ligula sodales.</p>
        </div>            
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should count to 10 instead of 12.

You want offset on both sides.

Like so:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-11 text-message">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur bibendum ornare dolor, quis ullamcorper ligula sodales.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-1">
      X
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-1">
      X</div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-11 text-message">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur bibendum ornare dolor, quis ullamcorper ligula sodales.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: let me try it now.

Comment: offset / space should be left side on FIRST ROW and offset / space should be right side on SECOND ROW.

Comment: @shibbirahmed Then you should remove the `col-md-offset-2` class from the second div.